# How to make HTMLCollection to display as a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created an unordered list in a div element. It all appears where it should but it shows incorrect values. The value shown is: "[object HTMLHeadingElement]" for what should have been car models. Any suggestions for how I can make the car models display instead? Thank you!

```
var name = document.getElementsByTagName("h4");
var myList = document.createElement("ul");
for (i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    var listItem = document.createElement("a");
    var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var listValue = document.createTextNode(name[i]);

    listItem.appendChild(listValue);
    myList.appendChild(listItem);
    lastdiv.appendChild(myList);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the text content of the `h4`. For that use `name[i].textContent`, as `name[i]` is a DOM Node.

```
var listValue = document.createTextNode(name[i].textContent);
```

Comment: Thank you, should have known that. Have a great day :)

Comment: Great it helped. Do close the question by marking it a correct answer :)